# Dropbox API in Codiegniter Accessing files inside folders?

Tags: codeigniter, dropbox

I want getting into the location of files which is in dropbox api. 
I want to assign the value in `detailsArray` if the folder have any file assign it. If it is folder then go inside folder and get that file. I want to assign the values of all files which is inside the apps folder and also that files which are inside in the apps folder.

PHP CODE

```
public function access_account($p)
{

    if($p == '/')
    {

        $curl = curl_init( 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto');  
    }
    else
    {

        $curl = curl_init( 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto'.$p);
    }

    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxx');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth = json_decode(curl_exec( $curl ) );
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($auth); echo '</pre>'; exit();
    return $auth;
    //print_r($auth);echo '</pre>';
}

public function get_folders()
{

    $p = "/";
    $result = $this->access_account($p);

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);'</pre>'; exit();
    foreach($result->contents as $folders)
    {
        if($folders->is_dir == 1)
        {
            $p = $folders->path;
            $result = $this->access_account($p);
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);'</pre>'; exit();

        }
        else
        {
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['path'] = $folders->path;
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['modified'] = $folders->modified;
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['size'] = $folders->size;
            $this->counter++; 
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->detailsArray); exit; 
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->detailsArray); exit;   
}
```

Comment: I think we should use some type of recursive function to retrieve all the folders files and folders inside folder files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually we have to put variable $p and $counter as global and update $this->p,$this->counter after the loop ends

```
public function access_account($auth_key,$p)
{

    if($this->p == '/')
    {
        $curl = curl_init( 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto');  
    }
    else
    {
        $curl = curl_init( 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox'.$this->p);
    }
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$auth_key );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth = json_decode(curl_exec( $curl ) );
    return $auth;
}
public function get_folders()
{

    $result = $this->dropbox($auth_key,$this->p);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';exit();
    foreach($result->contents as $folders)
    {
        if($folders->is_dir == 1)
        {
            $this->p= $folders->path;
            $this->access_account($auth_key,$this->p);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['path'] = $folders->path;
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['modified'] = $folders->modified;
            $this->detailsArray[$this->counter]['size'] = $folders->size;
            $this->counter++; 
        }
    }
    $this->counter = 0;
    $this->p = '/';
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($this->detailsArray); exit();    
    return $this->detailsArray;
}
```