# Downloading a file via curl in c++ from dropbox

Tags: c++, curl, dropbox

I want to download a file from a dropbox shared link using curl in a c++ program

I found a dropbox api pdf that showed me how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     CURL *curl;
     CURLcode res;
     /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
     curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
     /* get a curl handle */
     curl = curl_easy_init();
     if(curl) {
     printf ("Running curl test.\n");
     struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; /* init to NULL is important */
     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer 
     <ACCESS_TOKEN>");
     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:");
     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Dropbox-API-Arg: 
     {\"path\":\"/test.txt\"}");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download");
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
     /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
     res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
     /* Check for errors */
     if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",

     curl_easy_strerror(res));
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    printf ("\nFinished curl test.\n");
    }
          curl_global_cleanup();
         printf ("Done!\n");
           return 0;
         }
```

However, the comments supplied don't offer much explanation for me, and I can't get it to work.

I don't understand these three lines of code:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>");

headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:");

headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Dropbox-API-Arg:{\"path\":\"/test.txt\"}");
```

I think I have to replace some stuff but I don't know what

Comment: the file which is to be downloaded what's its url can you share it

Comment: match all credentials with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512884/dropbox-api-in-codiegniter-accessing-files-inside-folders

Comment: it is .exe file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoyb6wcgzceuxyu/BankAccount.exe?raw=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I think I have to replace some stuff but I don't know what" : Replace `<ACCESS_TOKEN>` with your *actual* access token.

You should also set the "Content-Type:" header to an appropriate value for the data you are fetching.

You must also change the value of the "Dropbox-API-Arg" header to match the file you are trying to get.

Comment: I am a little embarrased to ask but I have to ask, what is supposed to be my actual access token

Comment: @HBatalha See https://www.google.com/amp/s/blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/amp/ for a starting point

Comment: thanks, I have generated my access_token for my account
Now in "Content-Type:" should I replace with the type of date I want to download? in my case an .exe file?

Comment: thanks you @Jesper Juhl
I googled around and found this
https://www.lifewire.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109
according to this limk the content-type is 'application/octet-stream'
howevere in this stackoverflow post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459168/which-mime-type-is-correct-for-the-exe-file I found it to be 'application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable '

Comment: @HBatalha my initial guess would have been "application/octet-stream" for an executable, but if dropbox accepts "application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable" then I guess that works as well and is more specific. "application/octet-stream" is sort of the "fallback", in that it basically says; just give me raw bytes.

Comment: tried to upvote but my reputation is enough as I saw, I am new to stak overflow

Comment: @HBatalha Even as a new user you can still accept an answer.

Comment: this is what put when I changed the value of "Dropbox-API-Arg" - "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"D:\\Desktop\\\":\"/test.exe\"}".
not sure if it is correct though

Comment: @HBatalha that's obviously wrong. That refers to a local file on your own machine (or tries to at least). You need to specify the path of the file on the remote system. Read your original example again. And leave the "path" bit alone, that's a keyword, not to be changed.

Comment: ooh I see, so what exactly should I put there

Comment: I ahven't accepted the answer yet because my problem ins't completely solved yet, and I am still hoping some other people will help me as well
I thank you a ton for your patience so far @Jesper Juhl

Comment: @HBatalha I can't tell you. That depends on what you are trying to download and where it's stored/what it is named on the remote - which I don't know.

Comment: I am trying to download a small c++ console program I created as an exercise, I upload it to my dropbox just so I can I try to download using a c++ program
Here it it is if you want to check it out https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoyb6wcgzceuxyu/BankAccount.exe?dl=0

Comment: @HBatalha It looks like you just posted the correct (remote) path to your file "/s/zoyb6wcgzceuxyu/BankAccount.exe" that you need in that API call.. ;)

Comment: what do you mean bu "where it's stored/what it is named on the remote"
thanks again fro your patience

Comment: so I should put "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"//s/zoyb6wcgzceuxyu/BankAccount.exe\"}"?

Comment: @HBatalha I'm no expert on the Dropbox API, but that *seems* reasonable (except for the double "//" at the beginning which should probably just be a single "/").

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

Turns out I didn't have to use the Dropbox API

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
  size_t written;
  written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
  return written;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;

const char* destination = "D:\\Desktop\\test.exe";

fp = fopen(destination, "wb");

curl = curl_easy_init();

/* A long parameter set to 1 tells the library to follow any Location: header 
 * that the server sends as part of an HTTP header in a 3xx response. The 
 *Location: header can specify a relative or an absolute URL to follow.
*/
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L); 

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dropbox.com/s/09nd26tdyto23yz/BankAccount.exe?dl=1"); // "dl=0"changed to "dl=1" to force download

// disabe the SSL peer certificate verification allowing the program to download the file from dropbox shared link
// in case it is not used it displays an error message stating "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

CURLcode res;

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

fclose(fp);


if (res ==CURLE_OK)
    cout << "OK";
else
    cout << curl_easy_strerror(res);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks you guys for trying to help me. I appreciate